# Como usar subpasta como pasta principal sem alterar URL (site em joomla)

Tags: htaccess, joomla

Tenho um site que estou refazendo.

O antigo foi feito em wordpress (na raiz do site) e o novo em joomla (na pasta "novo")

Quero que ao acessar o dominio.com.br seja redirecionado para o dominio.com.br/novo, mas que o usuario veja dominio.com.br

Usei esse codigo no htaccess que funciona na pag inicial, mas quando entra no site novo, todos os links aparecem com o `/novo`, por exemplo, fica `dominio.com.br/novo/contato`

```
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{http_host} ^(www.)?paratodosacessibilidade.com.br$
rewritecond %{request_uri} !^/novo/
rewriterule ^(.*)$ /novo/$1
rewritecond %{http_host} ^(www.)?paratodosacessibilidade.com.br.com$
rewriterule ^(/)?$ novo/index.php [l]
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido.

Na Raiz criar o htacess com:

```
# Redirecionamento .htaccess do domínio principal para um subdiretório
# Não modifique a linha abaixo 
RewriteEngine on 
# Mude exemplo.com.br para o seu domínio. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?exemplo.com.br$ 
# Mude 'subdiretorio' para aquele onde está instalado o Joomla 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/novo/ 
# Não modifique as linhas abaixo 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Mude 'subdiretorio' para aquele onde está instalado o Joomla 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /novo/$1 
# Mude exemplo.com.br para o seu domínio, de novo. 
# Mude 'subdiretorio' mais uma vez 
# seguido por / e o arquivo principal do seu site: index.php 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?exemplo.com.br$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ novo/index.php [L]
```

E no configuration.php da instalação do joomla alterar as variáveis abaixo para:

```
var $live_site = 'http://www.exemplo.com.br'; 
var $log_path = '/home/username/public_html/logs'; 
var $tmp_path = '/home/username/public_html/tmp';
var $ftp_root = 'public_html'
```